# How to select minimum three file in file upload control

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, validation

**How to select minimum three files in multiple file upload Control**

Should i Add **AJAX FILE UPLOAD CONTROL TOOL KIT**

I want to select minimum three files for file upload control, and when i select less then three file then i want a alert message on client side itself.Where Should i change in my existing code?
Where i am doing wrong please guide me:

My code in aspx:

```
<label>Root Cause Image<span style="color: #ff0000;">*</span></label>
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload_RootCause" runat="server" 
    accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif" 
    multiple="multiple" 
    type="file" 
    name="image[]" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rev1" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="FileUpload_RootCause" 
    required="This Field is Required" 
    ErrorMessage="Only JPG and PNG are allowed" 
    ValidationExpression=".*((\.jpg)|(\.JPG)|(\.png)|(\.PNG))" 
    CssClass="red">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

<script>
    $("#FileUpload_RootCause").on("change", function () 
    {
        if ($("#FileUpload_RootCause")[0].files.length < 3) 
        {
            alert("You have to select minimum 3 images to proceed Further");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#imageUploadForm").submit();
        }
    });
</script>
```

**Above code is not working at all don't know why?, i tried 2nd approach i tried something like this**

And i am getting same thing as previous its not firing any alert message why ? and where i am doing wrong

```
 <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload_RootCause"  runat="server" 
        accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif" AllowMultiple="true"  />
<script>
        function ValidateFile2() {
        var fileCount = 
        document.getElementByID('FileUpload_RootCause').files.length;
        if (fileCount < 3)
        {
        alert("Please select minimum 3 images..!!!");
        return false;
        }
        else if (fileCount <= 0) 
        {
        alert("Please select at-list 1 image..!!!");
        return false;
        }

        return true;
        }
</script>
```

Comment: You have a 'required' attribute on the RegularExpressionValidator. I don't think that's valid. Same with all the attributes on the asp:FileUpload control. Perhaps try an html upload?

Comment: But I just tried what you have and it worked for me in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: i am also using Chrome but in my case its not working ??

Comment: There is nothing here about the jQuery Validate plugin.  Edited tags.

Comment: @sparky what should i add??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below code, it is working just check it.

```
<%@ Page Title="About" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="About.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3.About" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <label>Root Cause Image<span style="color: #ff0000;">*</span></label>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload_RootCause" runat="server"
        accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif"
        multiple="multiple"
        type="file"
        name="image[]" />
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rev1" runat="server"
        ControlToValidate="FileUpload_RootCause"
        required="This Field is Required"
        ErrorMessage="Only JPG and PNG are allowed"
        ValidationExpression=".*((\.jpg)|(\.JPG)|(\.png)|(\.PNG))"
        CssClass="red">
    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>


    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#MainContent_FileUpload_RootCause").on("change", function () {
                if ($(this)[0].files.length < 3) {
                    alert("You have to select minimum 3 images to proceed Further");
                }
                else {
                    $("#imageUploadForm").submit();
                }
            });
        });

    </script>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: should i add for checking <script>
if(!window.jQuery)
{
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.type = "text/javascript";
   script.src = "path/to/jQuery";
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
</script> <script>
if(!window.jQuery)
{
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.type = "text/javascript";
   script.src = "path/to/jQuery";
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
</script>

Comment: @dear vishal i dont much about java script how can i check  jquery loaded or not. can you pleas explain it??

Comment: Check is there any error occuring in console.   its showing error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_buttons' of undefined
    at m._constructor (dataTables.buttons.min.js:10)
    at new m (dataTables.buttons.min.js:6)
    at (index):455

Comment: @NitsPatel, your code is not working because of jquery issue. you need to load all required js files before you use it

Comment: then what should i do for loading all required js files any idea??

Comment: <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
just add above code before your script tag and check any other js file issue is occuring or not

Comment: i added but still same and while i checked  console its showing:-  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: sorry, please update with below line
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js">
</script>

Comment: @dear vishal nothing changes i replace <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script> to <script src="cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"> </script> but no any changes .

Comment: and console error change its showing :- GET http://localhost:63316/Admin/Project_Entry/cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I think i have to add AJAX FILE UPLOAD CONTROL TOOL KIT

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200505/discussion-between-vishal-modi-and-nits-patel).

Comment: you edited code will not work just because file upload ID is different and Script function that you call ID is different so how it works??

Comment: when your control placed inside content place holder, it automatically adding prefix and content place holder id, you can first check what id your control is generating and use it.

Comment: @dear vishal now i got my expected output as you mention content place holder id + file upload id comes adject thanx vishal

Answer (score 0):

**I tried Something like this**

```
     <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload_RootCause" runat="server"  accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif" required="This Field is Required" AllowMultiple="true"  onchange="Validate()"/>
     <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rev1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="FileUpload_RootCause" ErrorMessage="Only JPG and PNG are allowed" ValidationExpression=".*((\.jpg)|(\.JPG)|(\.png)|(\.PNG))" CssClass="red"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    <script >
     function Validate() {
          debugger;
          var fileCount = document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_FileUpload_RootCause").files.length;
          if (fileCount <3 ){
             alert("You have to Select Minimum 3 images to Proceed Further");
             document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_FileUpload_RootCause").value = null;
   }
}
 </script>
```